# Displaying dropdown choice in the dropdown box using python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an airplane booking programme using python. I want to know how to create a dropdown list with options using tkinter module and how to store the option the user selects.
for example, if a user chooses "Manila" from the dropdown list of destinations, "Manila" will be shown on the drop box and will be stored in the programme(for the purpose of displaying tickets). I also don't want my dropdown list box be opened in another window.

I am at a very elementary stage right now since this is a JC project so I would appreciate it if the solutions to my problem could be explained in simpler terms.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, pls have a look to this link: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which one: combobox, treeview, menu, etc?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.